# Rename hundred or more column names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with the John Hopkins Covid data for personal use to create charts.  The data shows cumulative deaths by country, I want deaths per day.  Seems to me the easiest way is to create two dataframes and subtract one from the other.  But the file has column names as dates and the code, e.g. df3 = df2 - df1 subtracts the columns with the matching dates.  So I want to rename all the columns with some easy index, for example, 1, 2, 3, ....

I cannot figure out how to do this?

Comment: Can you create a list of new column names?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

```
new_names=list(range(data.shape[1]))
data.columns=new_names
```

This renames the columns of data from 0 upwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-shape the data:  use dates and row labels, and use country, province as column labels.

```
import pandas as pd

covid_csv = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv'

df_raw = (pd.read_csv(covid_csv)
          .set_index(['Country/Region', 'Province/State'])
          .drop(columns=['Lat', 'Long'])
          .transpose())

df_raw.index = pd.to_datetime(df_raw.index)

print( df_raw.iloc[-5:, 0:5] )

Country/Region Afghanistan Albania Algeria Andorra Angola
Province/State         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-07-27            1269     144    1163      52     41
2020-07-28            1270     148    1174      52     47
2020-07-29            1271     150    1186      52     48
2020-07-30            1271     154    1200      52     51
2020-07-31            1272     157    1210      52     52
```

Now, you can use the rich set of pandas tools for time-series analysis.  For example, use `diff()` to go from cumulative deaths to per-day rates.  Or, you could compute N-day moving averages, create time-series plots, ...

```
print(df_raw.diff().iloc[-5:, 0:5])

Country/Region Afghanistan Albania Algeria Andorra Angola
Province/State         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2020-07-27            10.0     6.0     8.0     0.0    1.0
2020-07-28             1.0     4.0    11.0     0.0    6.0
2020-07-29             1.0     2.0    12.0     0.0    1.0
2020-07-30             0.0     4.0    14.0     0.0    3.0
2020-07-31             1.0     3.0    10.0     0.0    1.0
```

Finally, `df_raw.sum(level='Country/Region', axis=1)` will aggregate all Provinces within a Country.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the time and effort but I figured out a simple way.

for i, row in enumerate(df):
df.rename(columns = { row : str(i)}, inplace = True)

to change the columns names and then

for i, row in enumerate(df):
df.rename(columns = { row : str( i + 43853)}, inplace = True)

to change them back to the dates I want.